# Understanding JVM Behavior: How Does `switch` Handle String Hash Collisions?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, hashcode

During an interview, I was posed an intriguing question about how the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) handles a `switch` statement involving a `String` type. Specifically, I was asked whether the JVM employs `LookupSwitch` or `TableSwitch` for this operation. My initial thought was that it would utilize `LookupSwitch` due to the sparsity of `String` hashcodes. However, the interviewer added a layer of complexity by asking: "How does the JVM handle hash collisions when two different cases have the same hashcode?"

```java
class Solution {
    static int switchString(String i) {
        int res;
        switch (i) {
            case "A":  // hashcode 65
                res = 0;
                break;
            case "FB":  // hashcode 2236
                res = 1;
                break;
            case "Ea":  // hashcode 2236
                res = 2;
                break;
            default:
                res = 3;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(switchString("Ea"));
    }
}
```

Can you help clarify how the JVM navigates through switch cases involving `String` objects, especially when hash collisions are involved?

For the first part question, I found I'm wrong [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540892/is-string-a-numeric-type-regarding-switch-and-always-compiled-to-lookupswitch). the compiler has to pick either, a [lookupswitch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lookupswitch) or [tableswitch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.tableswitch) instruction

Comment: Who asks this as an interview question?!

Comment: @LouisWasserman a hedge fund firm, but due to a non-disclosure agreement, I'm unable to reveal the company's name.

Comment: if you really need to know,  use `javap` to disassemble  the class file generated by that code (the compiler on my system uses `lookupswitch`, and then compares to the literals,  assigning  an index to a temporary;  and then uses `tableswitch` to do the corresponding assignment to `res`)

Comment: (and a different compiler may do something else, or maybe this get optimized in future versions .... at the end it is some implementation detail and almost irrelevant for coding {unless when working directly with bytecode})

Comment: Unless you are interviewing for a Java compiler or JDK library position this is an irrelevant question. You could answer along the lines of 'I don't expect that issue to ever come up in the position I am interviewing for.' But there's not much you can do about smart-alec interviewers except move on.

Comment: @user207421 even worse, the interview question is an error in itself. The JVM doesn’t handle switch over string at all. The elaboration even acknowledges the interviewer’s wrong mindset by attributing the decision, which instruction to use, to the JVM. This reminds me on all those “how many objects are eligible to gc” questions where the only correct answer would be: “the gc exists so I don’t have to care and whatever answer you expect is likely to be wrong”.

Comment: @Holger Since it's a top tier hedge fund, the interviewer said that it's very important for them to optimize even 1ms. :)

Comment: @maplemaple I would not dismiss the need for optimizations at some places, but optimizations based on wrong assumptions about how the technology works (and typically done without rechecking the outcome with an impartial measuring tool) are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the decompiled .class bytecode

```
class Solution {
    Solution() {
    }

    static int switchString(String i) {
        byte var3 = -1;
        switch(i.hashCode()) {
        case 65:
            if (i.equals("A")) {
                var3 = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2236:
            if (i.equals("Ea")) {
                var3 = 2;
            } else if (i.equals("FB")) {
                var3 = 1;
            }
        }

        byte res;
        switch(var3) {
        case 0:
            res = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            res = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            res = 2;
            break;
        default:
            res = 3;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(switchString("Ea"));
    }
}
```

After examining the decompiled `.class` bytecode, it's apparent that the approach depends on the sparsity of the hashcodes of the strings, opting for either `lookupswitch` or `tableswitch`. In cases of hash collisions, the JVM employs a sequence of `equals` operations to distinguish between the colliding strings. This process involves a double `switch` mechanism to manage different cases effectively.

Answer (score 2):

We can reach some conclusions without particularly looking:

- `tableswitch` is used when the possible values of the expression being switched on are fairly clustered; `lookupswitch` otherwise.  Most hash codes are going to be well spread; if `tableswitch` gets used at all it'll probably be rare.
- It was never the case that we could use the hashcodes *alone* to accomplish the switching; we would always have to use `.equals` anyway to check that we've actually got the right string.  So presumably that's how we'll resolve hash collisions, by comparing them.  (Conceivably we could fall back to a binary search thing if there were a *ton* of hash collisions, but for that to be a realistic scenario, the *code* has to be written adversarially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to claim being an expert but I concur with your assessment on the `LookupSwitch` - Regarding hash collision I would imagine that's resolved with the `equals()` method.